# Is there a way to capture audio in browser with Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, browser, ionic3, ionic-native

This is probably a recurrent question but I couldn't find a way to make it work for now.

Until now I've used `cordova-plugin-media-capture` and couldn't make it work on my browser.

After running `ionic cordova run browser`, here's what I get:

> Ionic Native: tried calling MediaCapture.captureAudio, but Cordova is
>   not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and
>   b) include cordova.js in your index.html

After reading the [doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#capturecaptureaudio), the supported platforms are :

> Supported 
>   Platforms  Android  iOS  Windows

My question is, is there a way to make it work on my browser, if not, is there an other library or on another way to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The cordova plugin only works with cordova devices,
When a cordova plugin has browser support is supported by cordova devices through device's browser. It don't meaning will be supported by a browser on a PC/MAC/Linux.

Check this [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) to capture audio with HTML5